# LiipImagineBundle with Symfony

Tags: image, symfony, thumbnails, liipimaginebundle

I am trying to use LiipImagineBundle with Symfony to generate the thumbnails in my application. 
The thumbnails shall have a size of 125 x 125. 
I have the following setup in my config.yml:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        my_thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

And in my twig:

```
  <img src="{{ 'uploads/23/56ee92df677bf1907800427635419394.jpg' | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" class="img-thumbnail" />
```

I must seem something to be missing. 
What i checked so far is:

- intercept_redirects is set to false
- and that the original images exists under the given path.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Did you get any error ? Do you have the bundle enabled in AppKernel.php ? Check if the image path is correct (relative/absolute ...) Is the image path correctly generated (/media/cache/my_thumb/...) but image is empty (404 or 500 error) ? permission problem in /media folder ?

Comment: Hey Miro, 
I see no error, the Bundle is enabled in AppKernel. 
The relative image path is correct, the image path generated from the imagine_filter does not exist on the server. thats why i get confused. the image path throws a 404 error. i created media folder manually and set the mode to 0777 but didnt work :(

Comment: hmm, that is weird, so image is not generated on server, but it throws no error in the log ? i guess i dont know the solution, for me it works just fine on multiple websites.. try again read all instructions in here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/index.html (installation, configuration, ...) and make sure you follow all instructions. do you have installed and enabled php-gd extension ?